# retrieve the matched model in Z3py?

Tags: z3, smt, constraint-programming

In the following working example , How to retrieve the matched model?

```
     S,   (cl_3,cl_39,cl_11, me_32,m_59,m_81) = 
     EnumSort('S', ['cl_3','cl_39','cl_11','me_32','me_59','me_81'])

       h1, h2 = Consts('h1 h2', S)
       def fun(h1 , h2):

        conds = [
        (cl_3, me_32),
        (cl_39, me_59),
        (cl_11, me_81),
         # ...
             ]

    and_conds = (And(h1==a, h2==b) for a,b in conds)
     return Or(*and_conds)
```

For Example:
as the following solver

```
  s = Solver()
  x1 = Const('x1', S)
  x2 = Const('x2', S)
  s.add(fun(x1,x2)) 

  print s.check()
  print s.model()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want the value of `x1` and `x2` in the model produced by Z3. If that is the case, you can retrieve them using:

```
   m = s.model()
   print m[x1]
   print m[x2]
```

Here is the complete example (also available online [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/ePKW)). BTW, note that we don't need `h1, h2 = Consts('h1 h2', S)`.

```py
S, (cl_3, cl_39, cl_11, me_32, me_59, me_81) = 
      EnumSort('S', ['cl_3','cl_39','cl_11','me_32','me_59','me_81'])
def fun(h1 , h2):
   conds = [
     (cl_3, me_32),
     (cl_39, me_59),
     (cl_11, me_81),
   ]
   and_conds = (And(h1==a, h2==b) for a,b in conds)
   return Or(*and_conds)

s = Solver()
x1 = Const('x1', S)
x2 = Const('x2', S)
s.add(fun(x1,x2)) 
print s.check()
m = s.model()
print m
print m[x1]
print m[x2]
```